# Jedis | Redis BitMap Get All Enabled Bits

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Using Java Jedis (v 2.9.0). Trying to understand a strange behaviour with BitMap.

I'm having a bunch of numbers which I want to use them as offsets and enable their bit positions. I want to get them as a java.util.BitSet and get all their original values. Here's the code.

```
jedis.setbit("foo", 335, true);
jedis.setbit("foo", 1000, true);
jedis.setbit("foo", 1006, true); 

BitSet bitset = fromByteArrayReverse(jedis.get("foo").getBytes());

for (int i = bitset.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bitset.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + i);
            if (i == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                break; // or (i+1) would overflow
            }
        }

private static BitSet fromByteArrayReverse(final byte[] bytes) {
        final BitSet bits = new BitSet();
        if (bytes != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length * 8; i++) {
                if ((bytes[i / 8] & (1 << (7 - (i % 8)))) != 0) {
                    bits.set(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return bits;
    }
```

I'd have expected the output to be 335, 1000, 1006. But instead it prints the following as output.

```
DocId: 335
DocId: 1000
DocId: 1001
DocId: 1002
DocId: 1004
DocId: 1005
DocId: 1006
DocId: 1007
DocId: 1008
DocId: 1010
DocId: 1011
DocId: 1012
DocId: 1013
DocId: 1014
DocId: 1015
DocId: 1016
DocId: 1018
DocId: 1019
DocId: 1020
DocId: 1021
DocId: 1023
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe `String Jedis.get(String)` is returning what you think it should be (I haven't done much investigation).

However, if you use the method `byte[] Jedis.get(byte[])` specified in the super class `BinaryJedis` it'll work as expected.

i.e.:

```
BitSet bitset = fromByteArrayReverse(jedis.get("foo".getBytes()));
```